# Format Jan, 2017 in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to format the date like this: Jan, 2017. How it' s possible to achieve that format using moment.js? Now I' m writing like this:

```
moment(this.selectedDate).format('MMM-YYYY');
```

and the result is:

> Jan-2017

Comment: Why do you put a `-` in the `format` when you expect a `,`?

Comment: I thought moment js require writing - to separate month from year. My mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean that?:

```js
console.log(moment(Date.now()).format('MMM, YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```